# Only run JQuery on manual update

Tags: jquery, django

I have a script for populating some dropdown lists. 
the functions call a url in Django.

This is the issue I have:

When I want to load the page, the start_dates dropdown should be filled and the end_date dropdown should be kept empty.
When a value is selected in the start_dates dropdown, another script will run filling the end_dates dropdown.

However since I call the function to update the start_dates dropdown, the function to update the end_dates is automatically called which results in an error, because there is no value selected in start_date.

How would I be able to only call the funcion for end_dates when a date is selected manually?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ({}) {
        json_to_select("{% url "get_start_dates_list" %}", "#id_start_date");
    });

    $(function () {
        $("#id_start_date").change(function () {
            json_to_select("{% url "get_end_dates_list" 4545645 %}".replace("4545645", $(this).val()), "#id_end_date")
        })
    });

    function json_to_select(url, select_selector, oncomplete) {
        var opt = $(select_selector);
        opt.html("");
        opt.append($("<option/>").val(0).text("loading"));
        opt.change();

        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            var opt = $(select_selector);
            var old_val = opt.val();
            opt.html("");
            opt.append($("<option/>").val("").text("---------"));
            $.each(data, function () {
                opt.append($("<option/>").val(this.id).text(this.value));
            });
            opt.val(old_val);
            opt.change();

            if (oncomplete) {
                oncomplete();
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a variable that indicates if this is the first time that start date value is being set. and ignore changing end date value at this first time:

```
var firstTime = true;

 $("#id_start_date").change(function (){ if(!firstTime){
            json_to_select("{% url "get_end_dates_list" 4545645 %}".replace("4545645", $(this).val()), "#id_end_date");
  firstTime = false;}
        });
```

cheking the `firsttime` should be done when changing the value of the startdate and It might not be in the best place in my code, but its only to show the idea.